# Javascript Variable undefined and onchange not working

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined, onchange

I'm a beginner with Javascript so maybe this is easy for an expert to fix. I'm working on this: http://www.3dsbuzz.com/receng/test.php The source code is below.

The idea is that dragging an image into the white box adds a value to the text box which then triggers a mysql query and shows some data. But I have two problems:

1) When dragging the image into the white box, instead of displaying the image's value attribute, it just shows "undefined".

2) When I hardcoded a value instead of using the variable (on line 17), it goes into the text box fine, but doesn't trigger the mysql query, although it does trigger if you type it into the box directly.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
#div1 {width:175px;height:97px;border:1px solid #aaaaaa;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
function drag(ev){
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
}
function allowDrop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
}
function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")));
    var newtext = document.dragme.value;
    document.myform.users.value += newtext;
}
function showUser(str){
if (str==""){
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<input type="text" name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
</form>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Type "49" or "50" in the box above</b></div>
<br>
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>
<br />
<img id="49" name="dragme" value="49" src="http://www.3dsbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/mutantmuddsthumb.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
<img id="50" name="dragme" value="50" src="http://www.3dsbuzz.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/layton-thumb.jpg" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Feel free to post the relevant code and markup in the question. `;)`

Comment: Sorry, @JaredFarrish since there is only a little code and it is all relevant and since you would need to look at the page to understand what I was talking about, I thought it would be easier for people just to look at the source code. I'll edit it make sure I post the code on here in future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Images don't have an intrinsic `value` property.  Either you have to use `getAttribute` for the value, or, since the id and value are the same, just get the id of the dropped image:

```
function drop(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text")));
    var newtext = ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    document.myform.users.value += newtext;
}
```

2) the change handler only gets called if the user changes the value, not if a script changes the value.  You have to trigger it manually:

```
showUser(newtext);
```

Answer (score 0):

shouldn't

```
var newtext = document.draging.value;
```

be

```
var newtext = document.dragimg.value;
```

because draging isn't defined.

Comment: Sorry about that, you must have looked while I was making a quick change and saved it with a typo, that wasn't the original problem though.

Comment: np, I did just a quick look on your code and saw the typo. But as you said it wasn't the problem. :p